# XCode 5 Crashing on Load

Tags: ios, xcode

Suddenly my XCode 5 project is causing XCode to crash every time I open it.  **This is not caused by source control, as that is disabled**.  Here is the stack strace.

```
Process:         Xcode [1406]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.1 (5084)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5084000000000000~21
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 444172641
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [167]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-03-30 16:19:33.295 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          262248 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           178
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  240945 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   16
Anonymous UUID:                      FA7A25A2-D82D-0FAA-5A89-E06D0D5A2661

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B130a
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-5053/InterfaceBuilderKit/WidgetIntegration/View/IBViewIntegration.m:1410
Details:  Assertion failed: [positionWarningMessageKeySubstring length] || [sizeWarningMessageKeySubstring length] || [contentSizeWarningMessageKeySubstring length]
Object:   <IBUIView: 0x7fada1709f00>
Method:   -ibPopulateAmbiguityWarnings:forOrientationsWithMask:withAutolayoutStatus:context:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fad9ac14ed0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000109aaa825 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001088c57a9 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001088c5a8f _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001088c59f1 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010c0b9ede __110-[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibPopulateAmbiguityWarnings:forOrientationsWithMask:withAutolayoutStatus:context:]_block_invoke901 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x00007fff8d2df8a9 __NSDictionaryEnumerate (in CoreFoundation)
  6  0x000000010c0b9490 -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibPopulateAmbiguityWarnings:forOrientationsWithMask:withAutolayoutStatus:context:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7  0x000000010c0b85a8 -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibPopulateWarnings:forAutolayoutIssuesInDocument:withComputationContext:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  8  0x000000010c0b7af2 -[NSView(IBViewIntegration) ibWarnings:forDocument:withComputationContext:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9  0x000000011230705b -[NSView(IBAppKitViewIntegration) ibSwizzledNSViewWarnings:forDocument:withComputationContext:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 10  0x0000000112d3e858 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 11  0x0000000112d50491 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 12  0x000000010c0362ec -[IBDocument updateWarningsForMembers:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13  0x000000010c0372a6 -[IBDocument validateWarnings:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x0000000108e54fe8 -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] (in DVTKit)
 15  0x00007fff8d6ae8a1 __NSFirePerformWithOrder (in Foundation)
 16  0x00007fff8d2ba417 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation)
 17  0x00007fff8d2ba381 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation)
 18  0x00007fff8d2957b8 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 19  0x00007fff8d2950e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 20  0x00007fff89c39eb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 21  0x00007fff89c39b94 ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 22  0x00007fff89c39ae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode (in HIToolbox)
 23  0x00007fff8fabb533 _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 24  0x00007fff8fabadf2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 25  0x0000000108e29e31 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 26  0x00007fff8fab21a3 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 27  0x00007fff8fa56bd6 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 28  0x00007fff8d45a7e1 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 29  0x0000000000000002

abort() called
```

Comment: The problem is in a storyboard, so in the worst-case scenaro you'll have to recreate the project without the storyboard and redraw the storyboard... :( However, you should also send the project as is to Apple in a bug report, as this is exactly the kind of thing they want to know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seemed to be caused by IB Constraints that we specified on one of my views.  Here is what I did to "resolve" the issue.

1. Open the *.storyboard file that was causing the issue
2. If you happen to know what "Scene" was causing the crash (e.g. if you were working on one item and it suddenly just crashed on you) then find that scene in the XML.
3. Find all `<constraints>` sections within that scene and begin removing them one by one while continuing to try and open XCode.

Once you find the constraint that caused the issue you should be good.  Hopefully this helps save someone else some time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing plugins? They are located in the following directory:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins
```

If not try the following:

1. Deleting derived data `rm -rf ~/library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
2. Removing Xcode and re-installing it work?

Comment: There are none, that folder doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this by reverting changes to your last storyboard where before you added AutoLayout.  The new warnings and hints feature of Xcode for Autolayout is the culprit.  This problem should be reported to Apple also.

Comment: It was reported to Apple about 50 times as I submitted each crash report in anger :)